# Vagrant up - read error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

While installing vagrant for a new project I am getting the error. It happens when about 60% of `virtualbox.box` is downloaded.

How do I correct it ?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Vagrant 1.7.2, Virtualbox 4.3.26

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce your error:

```
$ vagrant init migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16' could not be found. Attempting
to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16
==> default: Adding box 'migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16' (v1.0.5) for provider: v
irtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/migosm/boxes/debian-7.6-ke
rnel-3.16/versions/1.0.5/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 7909k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> default: Successfully added box 'migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16' (v1.0.5) for
 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'migosm/debian-7.6-kernel-3.16' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: SO_test_default_1427480182231_55057
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2203.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2203 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2203
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/SO_test
$ vagrant ssh
Linux packer-debian-7 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1 (2014-12-08) x8
6_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Jan  4 16:49:00 2015 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@packer-debian-7:~$
```

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/297929/349115) to a question about the same SSL error suggests that the error message is telling you that the host is forcibly closing the connection for some reason. This could be because the Atlas servers were struggling with load during the time you were trying it and started dropping connections. Alternatively your connection may have been running for too long and it was forcibly closed by the web server.

In this instance you might be best using a download manager and directly downloading the box file and then using `vagrant box add [box file path]` to use the box. It does mean that you can't keep up to date with any changes to the box on the Atlas servers but should be fine otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I have done -- downloaded the box separately & used `vagrant box add` to use it. I'm not sure what I'll be doing if the server happens to change the box. Perhaps download the box again ?

Comment: I'd guess so. If you're still having issues (and also with other boxes too) then I'd guess it's your connection at fault in which case you'd have to rely on Vagrant adding some support for chunked downloads or for the Atlas servers to not time you out to be able to allow Vagrant to properly manage the box from the remote Atlas servers.